# Camera Video Capture Call On Pi3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I'm getting the following error when trying to record video on the Pi:

    `03-29 20:30:16.434 661-661/xxx.xxx.xxx D/Camera: Media Recoder Prepare Completedandroid.media.MediaRecorder@2da1655 
    Starting Video
    Media Recorder: android.media.MediaRecorder@2da1655
    03-29 20:30:17.900 661-661/xxx.xxx.xxx E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -19
    03-29 20:30:17.906 661-661/xxx.xxx.xxx E/Camera: Video Initialization Error
    java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
        at xxx.xxx.xxx.capture.VideoCapture.startRecordVideo(VideoCapture.java:176)
        at xxx.xxx.xxx.capture.VideoCapture$1.onOpened(VideoCapture.java:70)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:139)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)`

It looks to be a native JNI call error returned from `camera.v4l2.so`

Does anyone know what the `-19` error means?  Also, has anyone successfully 
captured video with Android Things on Pi?  Image capture works like a champ but I've had no success with video.

Comment: Can you include more of the stacktrace? There may be some more information about the error and why it may've been thrown

Comment: I updated to the raw log/stacktrace.

Comment: I'm really not sure what error -19 means.

Comment: Past references of "error -19" are to do with error while setting video size. Can you post code from VideoCapture.java?